# Prime numbers in physics of falling and collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

> A small ball moves at a constant velocity v along a horizontal surface and at point $A$ falls into a vertical well of depth $H$ and radius $r$. the velocity of the ball forms an angle $\theta$ with the diameter of the well drawn through point $A$. Determine the relation between $v,H,r,\theta$ for which ball can "get out" of the well after elastic impacts with walls (friction losses should be neglected).
>
> The answer is
> $$\frac{2nr\cos\alpha}{v}=2k\sqrt{\frac{2H}{g}}\tag{1}.$$

This question is a duplicate one but my question is little different I have got the same answer but it's given that $n$ and $k$ are prime but I can't understand why is it? Can anyone provide a physical intuition to this? what's the relation between prime numbers and a falling trajectory? If this question break any rules I am ready to delete it. I am sorry for this duplicate question but I don't know where to clear my doubt which is little different from the actual one.

The top view:

[image]

Comment: The angle θ and α are same.little mistake in question.

Comment: Can you link to the question which you say is nearly a duplicate of this one? Can you also link to (or refer to) your source for this question and the answer that you are doubting?

Comment: If the ball comes in along a horizontal surface, the angle between the velocity and the diameter at point A would be zero.  Also, what is the difference between r and H?

Comment: I'm really sorry,r is the radius.,H the depth of well. Also it's a horizontal surface so 2d , so it's not necessary to be along the diameter line then it's reduced to 1d.It can make an angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensuring that $n$ and $k$ are mutually prime ensures the ball gets out of the well at its first opportunity, and not after. Originally I thought that if $n$ and $k$ are solutions, then $2n$ and $2k$ should be solutions as well. But we need to recognize that by that point, the ball is already out of the well! It got out after $n$ and $k$ horizontal/vertical bounces, so it cannot escape after that.

By ensuring that $n$ and $k$ are mutually prime, there are no smaller integer divisors which would allow the ball to escape earlier. Making $n$ and $k$ integers will find you an infinite number of solutions where the ball is at the edge and lip of the well, assuming constant behavior of elastic collisions inside the well. Making $n$ and $k$ mutually prime will find you the *first* time when this happens, after which time we don't actually have that consistent behavior of elastic collisions anymore. The ball can only escape once, so we require a unique solution.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259141/     I am not doubting the answer in PSE I Just have a doubt from the book's answer ss krotov about why n and k is prime.

Comment: Thanks .but if n and k are co prime(gcd is 1) then also it will be the smallest answer as no common reduction factor.also why one of n/k can't be 1 then also there would be no common reduction (eg n is 4 and k is 1)

Comment: @Guji2203 Good point, edited my answer to focus on "mutually prime" rather than "prime". $n$ and $k$ don't have to be prime themselves, they just can't have any common integer factors besides 1. So, we could have $n$=4 and $k$=1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nuclear Wang I understood it...